# How to make fog with an image plane?

Tags: materials, image, volumetrics

I was trying to remake a scene from Assasin's Creed. It features the main character jumping from a pretty large building. I already have two volumetric lighting in my scene. Its literally impossible to use any more volumetric fog or smoke in it since my scene is pretty heavy with a lot of simulation and stuff. I recently saw Ian Hubert's splash screen. I saw that he used image planes for making steam besides the boat. Unfortunately I am using cycles and is not able to use the same node setup.

An example of what I want:

[image]

Ian Hubert's image(appended):

[image]

Node setup:

[image]

What happened is that it is completely transparent in cycles(with the same node setup)...

I would like to create the same in cycles with the same image (as I could.'t find one online).

Comment: create a plane, mix a Diffuse or Emission with a Transparent node in a Mix Shader, use a Noise or an Image Texture as factor?

Comment: That doesnt work out for me. I guess it is because the background is black in color

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your node setup you mix *Transparent* with *Translucent*. *Translucent* is not a good choice, it is generally mixed with an opaque node, it is made for objects like leaves, which are opaque when light hits from the front, and gets transparent when light hits from behind, which is not how smoke works, plus if you mix it with a *Transparent* it might be completely transparent on one side.

You should use a mix between *Transparent* and *Diffuse* or *Emission*, like that:

[image]

Comment: Perfect.. Just the node setup I was looking for .Thanks a ton.With the color ramp to conroll the opacity of the smoke,it is simlpy brilliant.